# How to remove duplicates from a list of object

Tags: java, duplicates

I have an excel file with following data (dummy)

```
a   b   c
d   b   c
e   b   c
f   b   c
g   b   c
e   b   c
d   b   c
d   b   c
d   b   c
```

I am reading this file and storing the result in a Set so that duplicates can be removed and I only get unique list.
Below is the what I tried

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\harshita.sethi\\Desktop\\ALLOT010T_Input_Keywords.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook w = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = w.getSheetAt(0);
int totalrows = sheet.getLastRowNum();

System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
String[][] data = new String[totalrows+1][sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells()];
Set<String[]> keySet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= totalrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
        HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
        // writing keywords from excel into a hashmap

        data[i][j]=cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    }
    keySet.add(data[i]);

}
Iterator<String[]> iterator = keySet.iterator();
System.out.println("Output Set is as below");
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String[] next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(next[0] + "\t"+ next[1] +"\t "+next[2]);
}
```

The output of this code is as shown below

```
Output Set is as below
d   b    c
e   b    c
a   b    c
d   b    c
d   b    c
g   b    c
e   b    c
f   b    c
d   b    c
```

The set didn't remove the duplicate. What other approach can I used to eliminate these duplicates.
Any column can have different or same value. So I cannot remove duplicates based on a particular column.

I want the entire row to be unique.

PS: This data is just dummmy. In real scenario I have more columns and any column value can be different which will make the row unique.

Comment: In your case you want the `d b c` and `e b c` duplicates to be be removed?

Comment: I'm trying to say that `d b c` and `e b c` are unique rows since both have one value different. But `d b c` and `d b c` are same since the entire row is same.

Comment: Why can't use create an object with three columns and use comparator for the object instead of array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set<String[]>` can't use a `HashSet` implementation, since arrays don't override the default `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation of the `Object` class.

Your alternatives are to use a `Set<List<String>>` (i.e. convert each `String[]` to `List<String>`, which can be done easily with `Arrays.asList()`) or a `TreeSet<String[]>` with a custom `Comparator<String[]>`.

For example :

```
Set<List<String>> keySet = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= totalrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
        HSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
        // writing keywords from excel into a hashmap

        data[i][j]=cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    }
    keySet.add(Arrays.asList(data[i]));
}
Iterator<List<String>> iterator = keySet.iterator();
System.out.println("Output Set is as below");
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    List<String> next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(next.get(0) + "\t"+ next.get(1) +"\t "+next.get(2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use comparator class :

You can use a TreeSet with a custom Comparator that compares the String arrays for equality.

```
Set<String[]> mySet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String[]>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
    //logic for comparison.
  }

});
```

Another better way is to use collections. Use a List instead of a String[]:

For example :

```
Set<List<String>> set = //...
set.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
set.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
set.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "d"));

System.out.println(set.size()); // 2
```

Comment: but he want value based comparison instead of hashcode